# Send dynamic SPAN value to PHP script using POST

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to send data from to the using PHP script. I use [jqCron](https://github.com/arnapou/jqcron) My problem is that I have dynamic SPAN value, but value of this span is not being sent using post function. I can not get the value

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $TiData = !empty($_POST['BCTiData']) ? $_POST["BCTiData"] : '';
    echo $TiData;
} 
?>
```

This is form

```
<form id="fo1" action="#" method="post"> 
    <div class="timer"> </div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="BCTiData" name="BCTiData" value="<span class="timer-span"></span>">
</form>
```

also I trying this method:

```
$degerSpan = '<span class="timer-span"></span>'; // Not working
```

How can I get the data in Span and how can I send with POST?
Thanks

*also I put it here [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/XaEmfnjT)*

Comment: You can't put a SPAN element insude a INPUT Value!

Comment: spans are not form fields, therefore they don't get sent when a form submits. You'll need JS to extract the span contents, stuff it into a form field, and submit that. And your HTML is fundamentally broken. That "embedded" span is outright illegal.

Comment: @MarcB I researched on the Internet and I tried examples but I could not do. Can you help me this issue please?

Comment: fix your html FIRST. until you do that, that form will never submit whatever you think it should.

Comment: Can you help me please @Cagy79 ?

Comment: First fix these errors: 1. you can't load JS files from Github, the browser does not allow that. Store them locally and link to them properly. 2.First include Jquery and then Bootstrap, otherwise the browser will throw errors.

Comment: I fixed mistakes @Cagy79

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use javascript to extract the value from the SPAN element, then put it in a hidden form field, and then submit the data.
This could be done in several ways. Here is some mockup code that should get you started:

```
<!-- the Span that will contain the data we're interested in -->
<span class="cronMDMtimer-span"></span>

<!-- The HTML Form that will submit the timer value, this is populated using javascript -->
<form onsubmit="myFunction()" id="my-form">
    <input type="hidden" name="timerValue" id="timerValue" value="not yet defined">
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<script>
// This function gets called once the user submits the form
function myFunction(){

    // First get the value from the cronMDMtimer-span
    timerValue = $('.cronMDMtimer-span').html();

    // Then store the extracted timerValue in a hidden form field
    $("#timerValue").val(timerValue);

    // submit the form using it's ID "my-form"
    $("#my-form").submit();
}
</script>
```